# Button image array animation with delay after every cycle

Tags: ios, animation, uiimage, uianimation

I am working on with a simple animation that I have 10 button and "on click" of one button ( for example 5) all button should start animate one by on but they are animating the same time, please let me know what can be done or ..... Thanks

```
    NSMutableArray* imagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int images = 0; images < 15; images++) {

    UIImage* buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"aaqqq00%02d.png", images]];
    [imagesArray addObject:buttonImage];
}

NSArray* reversedAnim = [[imagesArray reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];

int buttonTag = button.tag;

for (int images = 1; images <= 10; images++) {
    UIButton *animButton = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:images];
    if (images <= buttonTag) {
        animButton.imageView.animationImages = imagesArray;
        [animButton setImage:
         [UIImage imageNamed:@"aaqqq0014.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        animButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
        animButton.imageView.animationDuration = 1; //whatever you want (in seconds)
        animButton.imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1;
        [animButton.imageView startAnimating];
    } else {

        if (currentButtonTag_ >= images) {
            animButton.imageView.animationImages = reversedAnim;
            [animButton setImage:
             [UIImage imageNamed:@"aaqqq0000.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            animButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
            animButton.imageView.animationDuration = 0.2; //whatever you want (in seconds)
            animButton.imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1;
            [animButton.imageView startAnimating];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you iterate through your loop, have a variable that holds the desired delay, and add to it at the end of each loop. We'll call this `delay`.

Now, instead of calling:

```
[animButton.imageView startAnimating];
```

Do this:

```
[animButton.imageView performSelector:@selector(startAnimating) withObject:nil afterDelay:delay];
```

And each button will start animating after the accumulated delay.

Comment: I have done that but still they are animating at the same time after delay :(

Comment: And you're changing the delay on each iteration of the loop?

Comment: i put delay as constant, should i increase it?

Comment: Yes, otherwise, as you see, they will still all be at the same time. Your question said you wanted them to each start at a different time. So the delay needs to get bigger for each one.

Answer (score 0):

**You need to give some delay time and duration time.**

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.6
                          delay:2.0
                        options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^{S1Button.frame = CGRectMake(20, 10, 50, 10);S1buttonA.alpha = 0;}
                     completion:nil];
```

`Set this for every animation.`